# I have a list in excel I want to search in salesforce

Tags: excel, salesforce

Basically I have a list of Domains in excel I want to search salesforce for to see if there is any matches. Even if I could do them 100 at a time in 100 tabs that would be great just to automate the CTRL + C then CTRL + V would be an immense time saver. Any idea on how I could do this?

Comment: What does it means by " a list of Domains" ? Mind sharing the steps for "could do them 100 at a time" ? u may [edit] to add the info..

Comment: I mean I have a excel sheet with a column and each cell has a domain in it. If I could even automate the action of copy and pasting each domain to SF and pressing search in new tab that would be helpful.

Comment: want to search .. (1) if there is any matches.. (2) could do them 100 at a time.. (3) great just to automate .. (4) | Ur question have 4 parts (that is clear..), What is unlear to anyone trying help is... part (1)(2)(3) details.. depending one how your do each.. (4) will have different solution.. | Help others help you better by adding the info into the question by [edit] -ing it .. General guideline : [ask].. /(^_^)